# Twitter get tweets made by or mentioning me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, tweets

I am using rails and the Twitter gem. I want to display a list of, say 10, latest tweets or mentions of my twitter user. I have had a look at `home_timeline` but this returns all the content. I want to limit that to what is seen if I click on the "Tweets" section of my profile.

How should I go about this because I'm lost in the myriad of developer documentation and am unsure how to proceed?

Comment: Hi churchill614, did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) resource from the API:

> Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted by the authenticating user.

See [Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) on it's REST API for more information on all available resources.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Twitter GEM for Rails, use

```
Twitter.user_timeline('stackexchange')
```

This is for 20 statuses. For restricting count to 10.

```
Twitter.user_timeline('stackexchange', :count => 10)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What I actually ended up using was `Twitter.search('Username')`. Do you know of any gems that can parse the results and insert the correct hashtags and mentions etc in the right place or am I going to have to write this myself? Google isn't overly forthcoming.

Comment: Are you trying to search based on the username so that you can retrieve a user's mentions as well? And also, extracting the text field from the JSON does provide you with the hashtags and mentions.

Just an additional note. You can use the Twitter.mentions('username') to retreive data from a given user's mentions. This however requires authentication.

Comment: Yes, so I could get everything for the user. I stayed with search and used the twitter-text gem to parse the results.